# PowerShell foreach how to skip last element

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I have the follow array with the elements

```
$list = "A","B","C","1","2","3"
```

using foreach I can view all items in the array.

```
foreach ( $item in $list ) { $item }
```

I would like to print all elements in the array but the last one. As I need to add `;` at the end.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Could you please show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$List = "A","B","C","1","2","3";
($List[0..($List.Length-2)] -join '') + ';';
```

### Result

```
ABC12;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in as one-liner:

```
-join $List -replace [Regex]'.$',';'
```

First `-join` sticks all the elements in the array together. Then `-replace` & `regex` replace the last element with `;`.

**Regex** (`'.$'`)

- `.` = Matches any character except line breaks.
- `$` = Matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop with break worked for me.

```bash
$i=0
while ($true) {
  kustomize build $array[$i]
  $i++
  if ($i -eq  $array.Count ) {
    break
  }
  '---'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = echo A B C 1 2 3
$list | select -SkipLast 1

A
B
C
1
2


$list[-$list.length..-2]  # -1 is the last one

A
B
C
1
2
```